# Can't find WindowsUIButtonsPanel's button events

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I got 2 buttons in my WindowsUIButtonPanel, but I couldn't find button click event. I want to create minimize and close buttons.

Answer (score 0):

WindowsUIButtonPanel provides the [ButtonClick](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsDocking2010WindowsUIButtonPanel_ButtonClicktopic) event that you can use for this purpose. In the e.Button argument you will get the clicked button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either [WindowsUIButton.Click](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsDocking2010WindowsUIButton_Clicktopic)

```
WindowsUIButton button1 = windowsUIButtonPanel1.Buttons[1] as WindowsUIButton;
button1.Click += button1_Click;
...
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

}
```

or [WindowsUIButtonPanel.ButtonClick](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsDocking2010WindowsUIButtonPanel_ButtonClicktopic) events:

```
void windowsUIButtonPanel1_ButtonClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.Docking2010.ButtonEventArgs e) {
    if(e.Button == windowsUIButtonPanel1.Buttons[0]) { 
        // do something
    }
}
```

P.S. The [WindowsUIButtonPanel.ButtonClick](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsDocking2010WindowsUIButtonPanel_ButtonClicktopic) event is fired for regular buttons only (buttons with the `Style` property set to **PushButton**) and never occurs for check buttons. These raise the [ButtonChecked](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsDocking2010WindowsUIButtonPanel_ButtonCheckedtopic) and [ButtonUnchecked](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsDocking2010WindowsUIButtonPanel_ButtonUncheckedtopic) events instead.